# Linux Dirent: Getting a list of all folders inside a directory

Tags: c++, linux, dirent.h

Following is the code-snippet that I am using to get a list of all the folders within the current folder. I want to get red of the "." and ".." folders from the list but somehow cant.

```
const char* root_dir_c  = root_dir.c_str();
DIR *pdir               = opendir(root_dir_c);
struct dirent *entry    = readdir(pdir);

while (entry != NULL){
    if  ((entry->d_type == DT_DIR) && (entry->d_name != ".") && (entry->d_name != "..")){
        // DO STUFF
    }
    entry = readdir(pdir);
}
```

Can you please help ?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/charstring/stringeq.html

Comment: @melpomene much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entry->d_name` is a `char array` which doesnt work with `!=`, you will need to use `strcmp` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The `dirent` structure actually uses a `char*` not `std::string`. Thus you're going to compare two pointer values, which are never likely to be the same.

You have to use `strcmp()` for this case:

```
strcmp(entry->d_name,".") == 0
```